# Combining historical and near real-time data sources in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to educate myself using the free tier of BigQuery and for my first challenge want to create a trend following system for stock prices. For this I would have tables with historical stock market prices that covers 99% of my needs, but it's the last 1% that matters most as that part would represent live or near real-time data. The goal is to combine the 2 sources so that price trends include very recent data and create signals based on that. But...

Although the historical data part can be covered through periodically loading for instance .csv files, the near real-time data cannot be streamed as this is not allowed in the free tier. Apart from that I would always only need a single row as a fair representation for the guessed closing price per fund for that day. Then I could run this for instance every hour or so.

So my newbie question is how would one skin this cat? I assume I can't just call an API from a query to include the latest data and relate it to existing tables. But would I periodically  create, say, 10 .csv files all having a single line with the latest price data, upload those into tables, and then query the results? That doesn't look as a very elegant way but it may be the only one...

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> only need a single row as a fair representation for the guessed closing price per fund for that day

If the real time data is a single row, it is very reasonable to include this data in the query itself, say as query parameter, or even as literal part of the query (with proper escaping to avoid errors and sql injection).

Comment: And then query the API directly, Michael?